# Remove unwanted newline at start of section

Tags: line-breaking

In the code below there are two line breaks between "test" and the the text below it. How do you make there be just one?

```
\documentclass[7pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{multicols}{2}\lipsum[2]\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: text with unwanted automatic line break]

Comment: That is.. technically correct. Though requires you to already know the spacing, may fail in weird situations, ect... a different question suggests using `\\[-2\baselineskip]` before `\begin{multicols}` which works but feels hack-y.  A proper `\nolinebreak` option would be preferred, if such a thing exists.

Comment: The `\multicolsep` is added before and after the `multicol` environment in addition to the line spacing inserted by TeX. If you set `\multicolsep` to `0pt` you will get no _extra_ spacing; that is, it will be in the "next line".

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that's what I needed. Can you post a answer saying to use `\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}` at the top of the file or before the section in question so I can mark it as correct?